# How to deal with null values for Doctrine embeddables when using Twig?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, twig

I'm having trouble implementing Doctrine embeddables in my Symfony Application

I have this in a twig template:

`<td>{% if m.getSecurity.getIsin %}{{ m.getSecurity.getIsin }}{% endif %}</td>`

And when the template is rendered I get this error:

`Typed property App\Entity\ISIN::$value must not be accessed before initialization`

This is my entity definition:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Exceptions\InvalidCUSIP;
use App\Exceptions\InvalidISIN;
use DateTimeInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Embedded;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Embeddable;

/**
 * Security.
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="security")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\SecurityRepository")
 */
class Security
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Embedded(class = "ISIN", columnPrefix=false)
     */
    private ?ISIN $isin = null;

    public function getIsin(): ?ISIN
    {
        return $this->isin;
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setIsin(?ISIN $isin): self
    {
        $this->isin = $isin;

        return $this;
    }
}

/** @Embeddable */
class ISIN
{
    public const CHAR_COUNT = 12;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column (name = "isin", type="string", length=12, nullable=true, unique=true)
     */
    private string $value;

    /**
     * @throws InvalidISIN
     */
    public function __construct(string $value)
    {
        if (strlen($value) != self::CHAR_COUNT) {

            throw new InvalidISIN($value);
        }

        $this->value = $value;
    }

    public function __toString(): string
    {
        return $this->value;
    }
}
```

I recently changed to a simpler implementation that had the field `isin` as part of the main entity and things were working fine. I have some records in the database where the field `isin` is null and that should be fine...

Comment: Ok, so I found this https://wolfgang-klinger.medium.com/nullable-embeddable-with-symfony-and-doctrine-orm-51f6e2edf623 which, while somewhat of an overkill, did give me the answer I was looking for